# Angularjs: ng-repeat with different html tags

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Say one have a list of multiple type of data defined in a controller as follows:

```
$scope.list = [
    {text: "Remember BASIC?"},
    {code: "10   a = a+1"},
    // many additional lines…
];
```

Which we want to interpolate in the view depending on each individual type as follows:

```
<p>Remember BASIC?</p>
<code>10   a = a+1</code>
```

How would you do that?

[edit] Clarification about what to obtain

List is a descriptionof an arbitrary number of "paragraph" of arbitrary types.
Here is an more extensive list:

```
$scope.list = [
    {text: "Remember BASIC?"},
    {code: "10   a = a+1"},
    {text: "Bla bla"},
    {text: "Bla bla"},
    {text: "Bla bla"},
    {text: "Bla bla"},
    {text: "Bla bla"},
    {text: "Bla bla"},
    {code: "20   b = a+1"},
    {code: "30   c = b+1"},
    {text: "Bla bla"},
    // many additional lines…
];
```

And the expected result:

```
<p>Remember BASIC?</p>
<code>10   a = a+1</code>
<p>Bla bla</p>
<p>Bla bla</p>
<p>Bla bla</p>
<p>Bla bla</p>
<p>Bla bla</p>
<p>Bla bla</p>
<code>20   b = a+1</code>
<code>30   c = b+1</code>
```

etc.

It's not an issue to have an englobing tag, but I don't want an englobing tag for every single "paragraph".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what do you mean by

> // many additional lines…

but if your list looks like

```
$scope.list = [   

       {text: "Remember BASIC?"},
       {code: "10   a = a+1"},
       {text: "Remember Loundy?"},
       {code: "10   a = a+3"}  
   ....
  ];
```

you can use `ng-repeat-start /end`

please see here http://jsbin.com/zawige/3/edit

```
  <p ng-repeat-start="i in list" ng-if="i.text">{{i.text}}</p>
  <code ng-repeat-end ng-if="i.code">{{i.code}}</code>
```

Comment: You can toss an ngIf those to clear up the empty tags being generated.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca please see here http://jsbin.com/zawige/3/edit is working thanks to TheSharpieOne suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this with a directive that loads a dynamic template:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function getTemplate(type) {
    if(type === 'text') {
        return '<p>{{item.contents}}</p>';
    }
    else if(type === 'code') {
        return '<pre>{{item.contents}}</pre>';
    }

    return '{{item.contents}}';
}

myApp.directive("customListItem", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $element) {
            $element.html(getTemplate($scope.item.type));
            $compile($element.contents())($scope);
        }
    };
});


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
        {type: 'text', contents: "Remember BASIC?"},
        {type: 'code', contents: "10   a = a+1"}
    ];
}
```

You could probably write that `ng-repeat` so that you can use your original `list` structure.
The key here is `$element.html` that injects the correct template into the original and `$compile` that interprets the bindings in it.
Note that the original `custom-list-item` element will still be present in the DOM. No way you can eliminate that with `ng-repeat`.

[Here it is in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/k50y0car/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I would change the structure like so:

```
{
    content: "Remember BASIC?",
    type: "text",
}
```

Then you could do

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  <div ng-switch="item.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="text"><p>{{item.content}}</p></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="code"><code>{{item.content}}</code></div>
```

If you must/want to stick with the structure as it is now, you could nest `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  <div ng-repeat="(type, text) in item">
     <div ng-switch="type"> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your object model:

```
$scope.list = [
{
    text: "Remember BASIC?",
    code: "10   a = a+1"},
    // many additional lines…
},
{
    text: "Remember Test?",
    code: "10   a = a+4"},
    // many additional lines…
}];
```

Then in your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  <p>{{item.text}}</p>
  <code>{{item.code}}</code>
</div>
```

Comment: This creates extraneous div for each element, which is not compliant to the specs @Taras Kostiuk

Comment: hm... then you need to write custom directive and add needed DOM elements in directive link function